# Where is user authentication for Hamachi VPNs?

Tags: security, vpn, logmein, hamachi

I'm looking at LogMeIn Hamachi as a VPN and wondering where the user authentication settings are.  You can set a password for joining a network but that's a one-time event.  I see no settings to configure a username or password for logging on to the VPN.  It isn't even asking me to log me in to LogMeIn.com.

What user authentication options are available?

Answer (score 0):

Every hamachi client has a key (a file in your home directory) that is trusted or not by other peers (or a gateway) in the network you're logging in. So when your key is lost, network admin should evict your client from the network.